# Select query en hibernate con where clause

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate, spring-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con `Spring Web MVC` y `Hibernate`, () en el cual quiero obtener una lista de productos por categoría.

**Products.java**

```
package model.pojo;

public class Products  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer prodId;
     private byte[] prodPhoto;
     private String prodName;
     private int categoryId;
     private int prodTypeId;
     private int brandId;
     private float price;

    public Products() {
    }

    public Products(byte[] prodPhoto, String prodName, int prodTypeId, int brandId, float price) {
       this.prodPhoto = prodPhoto;
       this.prodName = prodName;
       this.prodTypeId = prodTypeId;
       this.brandId = brandId;
       this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getProdId() {
        return this.prodId;
    }

    public void setProdId(Integer prodId) {
        this.prodId = prodId;
    }
    public byte[] getProdPhoto() {
        return this.prodPhoto;
    }

    public void setProdPhoto(byte[] prodPhoto) {
        this.prodPhoto = prodPhoto;
    }
    public String getProdName() {
        return this.prodName;
    }

    public void setProdName(String prodName) {
        this.prodName = prodName;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public int getProdTypeId() {
        return this.prodTypeId;
    }

    public void setProdTypeId(int prodTypeId) {
        this.prodTypeId = prodTypeId;
    }
    public int getBrandId() {
        return this.brandId;
    }

    public void setBrandId(int brandId) {
        this.brandId = brandId;
    }
    public float getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

**Products.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 25, 2019 1:18:18 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.pojo.Products" table="products" catalog="houseofbeauty" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="prodId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="prod_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="prodPhoto" type="binary">
            <column name="prod_photo" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="prodName" type="string">
            <column name="prod_name" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="categoryId" type="int">
            <column name="category_id" />
        </property>
        <property name="prodTypeId" type="int">
            <column name="prod_type_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="brandId" type="int">
            <column name="brand_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="price" type="float">
            <column name="price" precision="12" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ProductDao.java**

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;
import model.pojo.Products;
import model.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class ProductDao {

    public static List<Products> ListProductByCat(int category_id) {
        List<Products> products = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("select prod_id, prod_name, price from products where category_id = " + category_id);
            products = query.list();

            session.close();
        }
        catch (HibernateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return products;
    }    
}
```

**CatalogController.java**

```
package controller;

import dao.CategoryDao;
import dao.ProductDao;
import dao.ProductTypeDao;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import model.pojo.Categories;
import model.pojo.ProductTypes;
import model.pojo.Products;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MenuController {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    @RequestMapping(value="/catalog/{category}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView ListProductByCat(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        List<Products> products = ProductDao.ListProductByCat(id);   
        mav.addObject("products", products);
        mav.setViewName("catalog");
       return mav;
    }
}
```

**catalog.jsp**

```
        ...
        <div class="row catalog">
            <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col">
                    <div class="product-block">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="#"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayImages?id=<c:out value="${product.prod_id}"/>" class="img-responsive"/></a>
                            <a href="#"><p><c:out value="${product.prod_name}"/></p></a>
                            <p class="price"><c:out value="${product.price}"/> руб.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-item-more">
                            <button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Купить</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>                    
        </div>
        ....
```

Haciendo de ésta manera obtengo este error:

```
Severe:   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: products is not mapped [select prod_id, prod_name, price from products where category_id = 1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at dao.ProductDao.ListProductByCat(ProductDao.java:32)
    at controller.MenuController.ListProductByCat(MenuController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: products is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 59 more
```

¿Cómo puedo imprimir la lista de productos obteniendo el valor de category_id?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que estás generando el query en lenguaje SQL convencional y no en HQL que es el lenguaje de consulta de Hibernate.

Tu query debería ser algo como lo siguiente:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Products WHERE p.categoryId = " + category_id);
```

Por otra parte, te sugiero hacer uso de vínculación de parámetros (parameter binding) para los queries y no armar los filtros dentro del String. Esto último te abre importantes brechas de seguridad relacionadas con inyección de SQL.

Siendo así, tu código debería lucir como el siguiente:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Products WHERE p.categoryId = :category").setParameter("category", category_id);
```